# Make a List<List<BigDecimal>> drom json value using Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

i'm getting this json:

```
{"channel":"123","data":"[[\"7132.09114\",\"0.00800000\"],[\"7131.71462\",\"0.08900000\"],[\"7122.94432\",\"0.75000000\"],[\"7122.87085\",\"0.20000000\"],[\"7122.38788\",\"0.00300000\"]]","event":"updated"}
```

How can i make List< List< BigDecimal>> from "data" value ? I was trying to get it using TypeReference in readValue(), but I got NPE, because this array inside of "".

Class which holds the data:

```
public class Result {
    @JsonProperty("channel")
    private String channel;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<List<BigDecimal>> data;
}
```

Comment: what is **data value**? is it your whole json?

Comment: From JSON point of view, `data` is of type String. Parsers like Jackson could not do what you want, I think you should do it your self ;)

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly are BigDecimal's in the JSON above? Ideally, an example of wished output as well.

Comment: @Haris I need to parse this array [[\"7132.09114\",\"0.00800000\"],[\"7131.71462\",\"0.08900000\"], .... to List< List< BigDecimal>>

Comment: Can you also post how does your class which holds the data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like this?

```
String jsonInput = "[[\"7132.09114\",\"0.00800000\"],[\"7131.71462\",\"0.08900000\"],[\"7122.94432\",\"0.75000000\"],[\"7122.87085\",\"0.20000000\"],[\"7122.38788\",\"0.00300000\"]]";

List<List<BigDecimal>> myObjects = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<List<BigDecimal>>>(){});
```

Comment: How'd you get that `jsonInput` from their String?

Comment: Thanks for this, i have decided to change data type from List<List<BigDecimal>> to String and apply your solution. It suits me

Comment: @Sotirios `List<List<BigDecimal>> o = mapper.readValue(response.getData(), new TypeReference<List<List<BigDecimal>>>() {});`

Comment: @Artem You could do it that way, but it's unnecessary and not clear in this answer.

Comment: @Artem I suggest you check your source of JSON info. It should return a proper JSON. Otherwise, you'll have to resort to dirty solutions like above to make your JSON parsing work.